# Angular2 - Html link to file download routes to home after click

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an **Angular2** application that expose some direct download links to files.

The files are located under :

`[MY_APP_FOLDER]\src\assets\OffertFile`

An example of the link href is this:

```
/assets/OffertFile/test.xlsx
```

The component.html link example is this:

```
<a href="/assets/OffertFile/test.xlsx" target="_self">
      <i class="fa fa-download fa-2x text-primary" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

The link works, I can download the file. The problem is that once I click the link, the application routes to home...

How can I avoid this?

Thanks to support

Comment: Try adding a 'download="test.xlsx"' property to the <a> tag. This will tell the browser its a download link and I think will also tell angular not to change routes. Not guaranteed but worth a shot.

Comment: It doesn't work at first test... I tried with <a [download]="./assets/OffertFile/2221/777.xlsx" target="_self"> and with <a (download)="./assets/OffertFile/2221/777.xlsx" target="_self"> but I get compilation errors... Do I need to import something ?

Comment: Keep the href, here is what you should try <a href="/assets/OfferFile/2221/777.xlsx" download="someFile.xlsx" > click here </a>

Comment: might be helpful
https://scotch.io/tutorials/routing-angular-2-single-page-apps-with-the-component-router

Comment: This works, now I check what you put in your answer!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please add the `download` attribute to the `<a>` tag. This will prevent rout changes and tell the browser it is a download link:

> HTML  docs: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

```
<a href="/assets/OffertFile/test.xlsx" target="_self" download>
      <i class="fa fa-download fa-2x text-primary" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Ahmed, actually it is not working... It downloads an empty file... I think its a routing problem...

Comment: it downloads an empty file if the `href` is incorrect. I tested it on my local, works just fine and downloads the file I point `href` to.