# Easiest/Best way of Linking/Merging or (worst case) converting Javascript application to angular(2,4,5) application

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular2-routing

I have two applications, one made using angular2 (solutions to 4 and or 5) are also welcome for testing. The other application is made using native javascript and jquery. No I need to some link a part of the angular app to the index page of javascript file. How best can I achieve this? As [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806329/angular2-html-link-to-file-download-routes-to-home-after-click) posts say, using a mere `href` will route to the home url of the angular app. 
Thanks

Comment: How is your Angular app deployed? Do you run it locally via the CLI? Also, please clarify: what do you mean by 'index page of javascript file'? Do you mean the index.html page which runs your native javascript/jquery?

Comment: @dextercom, yes. I run everything locally. And yes by index.html i mean the html page that runs my javascript. Furthermore, for convenience i put all the javascript files and the html page of the native javascript app in a subfolder under the assets directory of the angular app. If that will make it easier :). I should probably add this to the main question too.

Comment: And what do you hope to achieve by that? Angular has only one index page, because its a SPA and its routing structure is determined by the <base href=""> tag. If your applications are totally different then you can simply run the native javascript one independently (lets call it 'a non SPA app'), and while your angular app is being run locally you can anchor it to your non SPA app via a simple link which will contain your localhost domain together with relevant port. I.e: <a href="http://localhost:4200">Link to my SPA app</a>

Comment: @dextercom, that only works if I want to access the SPA app from the non SPA app. But what I want is the opposite. To link to the non SPA app via the SPA app.